# Suspicious pointer conversion

Tags: turbo-c

I got a suspicious pointer conversion error here. What might be the reason of this error?

I also initialized the `code[]` array globally as `int *code[128]={0};`

```
void encode(const char *s, int *out)
{
    while(*s)
    {
        out=code[*s];
        out+=strlen(code[*s++]);   //this is where i got the error.
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the type of `code` `const char *`? Btw, welcome to SO!

Comment: No, its int as declared, int *code[128]={0};
Thanks

Comment: That's it then, strlen takes a pointer to `const char`. You can't use an element of `code` as an argument for strlen. The compiler doesn't see any explicit casting made by the programmer (you) and thus warns you of suspicious pointer casting for int to const char

Comment: What method can I replace in that situation?

Comment: I can't say you're using strlen wrongly yet, because I don't know what you intended to use it for. What did you think strlen would give you? Rephrasing, what did you intend to use strlen for?

Comment: I need it to know the length of the integer.

Comment: Length as in number of digits, number of bytes? strlen gives the length of a null-terminated string in no. of chars, so other methods should work

Comment: ? No, strlen won't work here! What units are you referring to with regards to the length of the integer?

Answer (score 0):

When you will assign a particular type pointer variable with address of different type, such type of automatic type conversion is known as suspicious type conversion.

strlen requires const char *, while int *code[128] means code is an array of int *, so code[*s++] is a int *.

When int * is supplied to const char *, you get this error.

Generally supply int * pointer to strlen isn't a good idea because strlen will end when a byte is '\0'. You have a good chance to have 0 in a 4 bytes int. E.g., an integer 3 will have 3 bytes of 0, and 1 byte of 3.